# currentpage.getContentAsPDF() renders hidden tables

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, getcontentaspdf

I have created a visualforce page (pop up window) showing a confirmation letter containing student information and booking details. The page has a table in the header (or simply at the top) that provides two buttons (apex:commandbutton):

One executes a simple javascript function to print the current window. This button will hide the table containing the buttons prior to printing. This works fine.

The second button renders the current page to PDF (currentpage.getContentAsPDF) and attaches the blob to an email and sends it out. It also hides the button table before running its action.

However, the currentpage.getContentAsPDF method re-renders to entire page, hiding tables as part of the button functionality has zero effect. Interesting is that the buttons themselves are not printed. This as I'm using this CSS to hide them:

```
@media print { .no-print, .no-print * { display: none !important; } }
```

```html
<apex:commandButton id="printbtn"
    image="{!URLFOR($Resource.PrintButtonIcon)}"
    **styleclass="no-print"**
    value="Print"
    onclick="hideButton('{!$Component.printbtn}');window.print();"                                           
    oncomplete="showButton('{!$Component.printbtn}')"/>
```

So the getContentAsPDF() function seems to acknowledge the no-print class settings for the buttons and other apex: components, but ignores it for standard HTML tags such as [table]. Even if the html table is encapsulated by for instance apex:form or apex:panelgroup, the html table is rendered.

How can I hide an HTML table when calling currentpage.getContentAsPDF?

Comment: No JavaScript is executed by `getContentAsPDF` and that call also runs in a separate transaction. So CSS (as described here [The Flying Saucer User's Guide](https://flyingsaucerproject.github.io/flyingsaucer/r8/guide/users-guide-R8.html)) is the primary tool you have so focus on debugging that. Or a more brute-force approach is to pass flags into the page that conditionally render parts of it. Agree what you are seeing is confusing.

Comment: Solved the problem by removing the HTML tables and replaced them with <div> tags. Could do so because I used the table only for a single row/column with a border and background colour. This can be achieved with a <div> just the same.
For some unexplainable reasons only <table> tags are ignored in terms of the no-print CSS class. The <div> tag works just fine. I conclude that there is an issue with the getContentAsPDF() rendering engine.